# Can not vote to close as duplicate if open in another tab

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, vote-to-close

If I try to vote to close question A as a duplicate of question B, and I have question B open in another tab of my browser, the submission button does not respond to a press.

I'm using a Samsung Galaxy (an Android device), using the web browser, not the app. I'm using the "desktop view" setting, rather than the mobile version  of the site.

Answer (score 4):

Looking at [Which browsers are officially supported? And what else do I need?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/71208/187824)

The "desktop view" (AKA "Standard View") is **not supported** on Android browser. Only "Mobile view" is supported on Android browser (Version: 4.x, 3.x, and 2.3).